# how to install bag_to_images

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am very new to ROS and I am having a lot of trouble installing bag_to_images.

I have a rosbag file of a video I recorded from my robot and I need to convert it to a movie(avi or mpeg). I was hoping to use bag_to_images to do this.

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12337/how-to-install-bag_to_images/) by [alexiip](https://answers.ros.org/users/1533/alexiip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-02**:
Please provide more information for your question: See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`bag_to_images` appears to be c-turtle specific, which may very well mean that it won't work on more-modern ROS.

Other than that, we're going to need more information. What *kind* of trouble are you having? What have you tried?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0